# Add AWS SDK to IntelliJ project without Maven or Gradle

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, intellij-idea

I'll start this off by saying that I'm not a Java dev, I work in a .NET software house, but somehow we have ended up needing to modify some legacy java code.

So I have a project which I've opened up with IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2016.2. As far as I can tell this doesn't use Maven or Gradle or any other dependency management tool, and as I have no idea what I'm doing with Java projects I'm not going to start trying to understand that now.

I'm trying to add the Amazon AWS SDK to my project so I can upload some files to an S3 bucket. I've downloaded the SDK from the AWS site, and extracted the jar files into the lib folder of my project root. I've tried numerous ways of adding these as dependencies, right click the jar files and add as library, go into settings, modules, dependencies, click the plus and add the jars etc. When I build the project it builds fine, and intellisense if picking up the classes and methods when writing the code to utilise the SDK.

However, as soon as I run the app, I get a "java.lang.NoClassDefFound" for the com/amazonaws/AmazonServiceException package as the containing class is instantiated.

This could well be something to do with the "CLASSPATH" that I hear so much about (but don't fully understand), but my understanding was that IntelliJ handled this when adding the jars as a dependency. I've also tried adding all the jars from the "third-party" directory from the downloaded AWS zip file, and adding those as dependencies as well, but it still doesn't want to work.

Incidentally, I'm adding the jars to the lib folder so they are included in source control.

Any suggestions on how to use the AWS SDK without using Maven or Gradle?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

What I've done is to manually add all the jar files into the **External Libraries**.

1. Go to **File** > **Project Structure**
2. In the left window pane, choose **Modules** under *Project Settings*
3. Click on the **Dependencies** tab
4. Click on the **+** sign and select **1 JARs or Directories**
5. Navigate to the folders containing the jar files (include third-party dependecies also) and click **OK**

See [My IntelliJ screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9ASQ.png)